# 'self' used before self.init call error while using NSCoding on a custom class

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding, nscoder

I'm trying to encode a custom class so I can save it using `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject`

but when I try to conform to the NSCoding protocol, I get this error :  'self' used before self.init.  Here is my code:

```
class MemberRewardsInfo: NSObject, NSCoding {
var id: Int?


  required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    guard let unarchivedId = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("id") as? Int

      else {
        return nil
      } 
  }


  func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encodeObject(id, forKey: "id")
  }
}
```

its pretty annoying, not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is sort of misleading, but you need to make `init(coder:)` a designated initializer.

You need to modify your `init(code:)` to something like this:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    guard let unarchivedId = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("id") as? Int else {
            return nil
    }
    self.id = unarchivedId
    super.init()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's upset about `convenience`.  The assumption is that if you create a convenience initializer, it's going to chain to a "real initializer.

Answer (score 0):

When using a convenience initializer, just call the designated initializer, in your case, self.init(), inside block. See [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html) in Apple docs for an explanation.

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    guard let unarchivedId = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("id") as? Int

    else {
        return nil
    }
    self.init()
    self.id = unarchivedId
```

}